# OpenGL: Acquiring only a stencil buffer and no depth buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to acquire a stencil buffer, but not suffer the overhead of an attached depth buffer if it's possible, since I wouldn't be using it.  Most of the resources I've found suggest that while the stencil buffer is optional (excluding it in favour of gaining more depth buffer precision, for example) I have not seen any code that requests and successfully gets only the 8-bit stencil buffer.  The most common configuration I've seen being 24 bit depth buffers with an 8 bit stencil buffer.

Is it possible to request only a stencil buffer with a color buffer?

If it is possible, Is it likely the request would be granted by most OpenGL implementations?

The OpenGL version I'm using is 2.0

**edit:**

The API I'm using to call OpenGL is SFML, which normally doesn't support stencil allocation for it's FBO wrapper objects, though it allows it for the display surface's framebuffer.  I edited the functionality in myself, though that's where I'm stuck.

```
glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT, width, height));
```

This line decides the storage type I assume.  However, `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT` is the only define I've found that specifies a stencil buffer's creation.  (there's no GL_STENCIL8 or anything similar at least)

Comment: You should be able to. I know you can definitely do it with FBO's.

Comment: Yes. It's possible, it's depends on what you use for windowing how you'd implement it. What are you using for windowing (glut/SDL/GLFW etc.)?

Comment: I'm using SFML, which 'normally' doesn't allow it's FBO wrapper to request a stencil buffer.  But I hacked that in myself.  I can edit that into the question

Comment: I don't use SFML, but to me it looks like you can: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-opengl.php. I'll write a small demo application when I get home.

Comment: Xonar - Oh gosh, I'd feel bad if you went through all that trouble... I've hacked the API to near unrecognizability anyway, gutting most of the stuff that messed with OpenGL's state.  It's pretty much just raw OpenGL at this point.

Comment: The storage type your looking for is GL_STENCIL_INDEX8

Comment: Xonar - OH!  Aw, thank you!  Though, it feels 'wrong' somehow to have 40 bits per pixel.  I wonder if it'll cause any alignment issues...

Comment: I can't seem to get it working with just the stencil buffer with SFML (Without using extensions that aren't guaranteed to be in OpenGL 2.0 at least), but if you've got it working then you can post a answer to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Researching `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8` that was mentioned in the comments, I came across the following line in the the official OpenGL wiki, http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples#Stencil

> NEVER EVER MAKE A STENCIL buffer. All GPUs and all drivers do not support an independent stencil buffer. If you need a stencil buffer, then you need to make a Depth=24, Stencil=8 buffer, also called D24S8.

Stress testing the two different allocation schemes, `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8_EXT` vs `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_EXT`, the results were roughly equal, both in terms of memory usage and performance.  I suspect that it padded the stencil buffer with 24bits anyway.  So for sake of portability, going to just use the depth and stencil packed scheme.