# What is desktop OpenGL equivalent to GL_STENCIL_BITS?

Tags: macos, opengl-3

On OpenGL ES 2.0 API, I could use `glGet*` function with `GL_STENCIL_BITS` symbol to get current stencil buffer's bit-size.

What is the equivalent of the symbol on desktop OpenGL API? I am targeting OpenGL 3.x API or later.

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked with OSX, but in GL a separate stencil is going away, and a packed depth+stencil is to be used. You can use glGetIntegerv with GL_MAX_DEPTH_TEXTURE_SAMPLES as in http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGet.xhtml.

Also refer to [OpenGL: Acquiring only a stencil buffer and no depth buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115663/opengl-acquiring-only-a-stencil-buffer-and-no-depth-buffer)

Comment: But even with composited stencil buffer, there's a defined bit-size, and I still believe there's a way to get the bit-size.